# after use html and javascript to make login page, want to prevent others go to linked page directly

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I have a html login page and use javascript to hide the user name and password:

Javascript:

```
function myFunction(){
var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
 var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;

if(user == "user1" && pass == "zzxx"){
          window.location.href="about.html"}

 else if(user == "user2" && pass == "xxzz"){
        window.location.href="about2.html"}
 
   
else if(user == "user3" && pass == "ooppp"){
        window.location.href="about3.html"  
   
     } else{
  alert("Incorrect username or password");
  }
```

HTML:

```
    html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Login</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
   <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/invisible_debut.js" ></script>

  </head>
  <body>

   <div class="loginBox">
   
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <div class="textbox">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        <input  name="username" id="username" type="text"placeholder="Username">
    </div>

    <div class="textbox">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        <input name="pass" id="pass" type="password"placeholder="Password">
    </div>

    <button  value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" 
    onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>

 <div class="bg"></div>
   </html>
```

I want to prevent the user to go to about.html by directly typing ..../about.html
I only want people to login through user name and password.
How can I do that?
Many Thanks!

Comment: Kind of a hack, but you could use `document.referrer`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store some information on

```
localStorage
```

to make sure that this user already visited and logged in to your website.
When users will try to go directly to the about page without logging in - you can redirect them to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Use session-storage or local-storage to store the value of the user, then check that value in about page, if not exists then redirect the user back to the index page.

```
function myFunction() {

  var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;

  if(user == "user1" && pass == "zzxx") {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("user", "user1"); 
    window.location.href="about.html"
  } else if(user == "user2" && pass == "xxzz") {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("user", "user2");
    window.location.href="about2.html"
  } else if(user == "user3" && pass == "ooppp") {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("user", "user3");
    window.location.href="about3.html"
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect username or password");
  }
```

Use the above session-storage-item in about page

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("user")) {
    var usr = window.sessionStorage.getItem("user");
    if(user != "user1") {
      window.location.replace("index.html");
    }
  } else {
    window.location.replace("index.html");
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this work if javascript is disabled?

Comment: @RobMoll, definitely will not work. In the question there is a piece of Javascript, so I used that piece of code and assumed JS will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `document.referrer` to check if its your website or not

Comment: This answer already exist in the command section, you can improve your answer by  updating it and add some explanation to it, more on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer